# NaN string in source files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We receive multiple large (~ 1gb) JSON files from a vendor on a daily basis.  There are about 15 different and fairly complex schemas.  Every so often, we receive the string "NaN" (with the quotes) in  fields that are otherwise always numeric.  Since we're having Spark infer the schema when we read into a dataframe, when this happens, Spark obviously decides this is a string.  This is causing multiple issues downstream.

Other than trying to actually define a schema for each json file, or casting each column individually as a long or whatever, is there any way to handle this?

Comment: You've probably already noticed (that's why you're adding that your `"NaN"` values have quotes in them) but with `NaN` values (without quotes) it would work. This is thanks to the `allowNonNumericNumbers` option which is `true` by default. You probably have no control over it but just adding this for info.

Comment: Also, this is not really an answer but I would try to avoid inferring schemas of files in a production environment, the cost to do that is quite high. Spark will read your file twice: once to infer the schema and once to read in the data. The results are also not robust (as you are noticing, it works when there is no `NaN` but doesn't when there is one).

Comment: @Koedlt - if only I could get an actual schema with data types from the vendor... I guess one alternative is just to force everything to be a string?

Comment: ahhh yes that's annoying. Do these schemas change often? It might be worth it to go through the trouble of defining these schemas (best case scenario). If having every field be a string is not necessarily problematic to you, you could do that. Forcing everything to be a string can be done by adding `.option("primitivesAsString", "true")`  when reading in your json.